# Find the shortest way to advance a counter to a certain number

Tags: code-challenge, test-battery

I have a counter. It's a small device that looks like this:

[image: counter]

The display goes from `0000` to `9999`. It has a little push-button at the top that increases the count by 1, and a little knob at the right whose purpose is to reset the counter back to 0.

Now, the thing about the little knob is that if you turn it backwards, you can make it increase any digit that you want once you turn it forwards again. So if I push the counter button 10 times so that the counter shows `0010`, I can then turn the knob backwards until i hear a tiny click, then turn it forwards again and make it go straight to `0090`.

But, the knob will always increase all occurrences of the same digit by 1 every time it pushes numbers forward. So if the counter shows `6060`, you can only make it increase to `7070`, not to `6070` or `7060`. Also, the knob will roll `9`s over to `0` without carrying, so `0990` will advance to `0000` instead of `1000` or `1100`.

---

I want to know the most efficient way to set the counter to a certain number. Your task is to write a program or function that will determine the shortest sequence of button pushes and knob advancements required to do so.

Your program will take as input a 4-digit number from `0000` to `9999`, and return a series of steps in the following format:

```
> 0001
C
> 0093
C12345678C12345678CCC
> 1000
C12345678C12345678C12345678C12345678C12345678C12345678C12345678C
> 9999
012345678
```

Where `C` stands for "push the counter button" and any digit `D` from 0 to 9 stands for "use the knob to advance all occurrences of `D` by 1".

Your program must produce a valid sequence of steps for all possible four-digit combinations, and will be scored by the total number of steps required for all 10,000 cases. In the case of a tie (most likely when the optimal algorithm is found), the shorter code will win.

Comment: What happens if you turn the knob forward? Will it turn `0010` into `0020` in that case? Or can you only turn the knob backwards? And also, does each "D" count as "D" number of advancements of the knob (for instance, does `1234567` mean turn the knob 1 time, then 2 times, then 3 times, so on so forth)? Or does it just signify each separate knob turn (for instance, does `1234567` just mean turn the knob 7 times)?

Comment: Looks like the above and the below are unrelated.

Comment: The knob can even choose digits in the below.

Comment: Turning the knob forward will either advance 0010 to 0020 or 1111, depending on the position the knob is already in. You turn the knob backwards to set its position, and then forward to advance the digits.

Comment: each D signifies a separate advancement of the digits, so `1234567` signifies turning the knob 7 units.

Comment: Seriously, this guy _needs_ his counter at the correct value!!!! NOW!!!

Comment: @edc65 `0093:C12345678C12345678CCC`. After `C12345678`: `0009`. After another `C`: `0010`. After another `12345678`: `0090`. Then after `CCC`: `0093`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth, 327763 steps (optimum, 130 bytes)

Since the online compiler is inept at dealing with such enormous task, I have given it less work, so that it only generates `0`, `1`, and `1111`. However, it can theoretically solve the problem, because it uses the same algorithm as the Lua at the top.

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3DY.d%28%280k%3BV1%3DZYFGY+XZG%3Dk%40YG%3DN%25%22%2504d%22GV4%3Db%40NH%3Ddi%3ANb%25%22%25d%22ehibTT+XZd.x%3F%3El%40Ydlk%2Bkb%40Yd%2Bkb%29%3DbhGI%3CG9999+XZb.x%3F%3El%40Yblk%2Bk%5CC%40Yb%2Bk%5CC%29%29%3DYZ%3B%40YQ&input=1111&debug=0)

```
=Y.d((0k;V53=ZYFGY XZG=k@YG=N%"%04d"GV4=b@NH=di:Nb%"%d"ehibTT XZd.x?>l@Ydlk+kb@Yd+kb)=bhGI<G9999 XZb.x?>l@Yblk+k\C@Yb+k\C))=YZ;@YQ
```

---

How it works:

```
=Y.d((0k;V53=ZYFGY XZG=k@YG=N%"%04d"GV4=b@NH=di:Nb%"%d"ehibTT XZd.x?>l@Ydlk+kb@Yd+kb)=bhGI<G9999 XZb.x?>l@Yblk+k\C@Yb+k\C))=YZ)@YQ
                  assign_copy('Q',eval_input())
=Y.d((0k;         assign_copy('Y',dict(0=k))
V53               for N in range(0,53):
=ZY                   assign_copy('Z',Y)
FGY                   for G in num_to_range(Y):
 XZG=k@YG                 no_print(Z[G] = assign_copy('k',lookup(Y,G)))
=N%"%04d"G                assign_copy('N',format("%04d",G))
V4                        for H in range(0,4):
=b@NH                         assign_copy('b',lookup(N,H))
=di:Nb%"%d"ehibTT             assign_copy('d',base(replace(N,b,format("%d",mod10(increment(base(b,10))))),10))
 XZd.x?>l@Ydlk+kb@Yd+kb       no_print(Z[d]=try_and_catch(greater_than(Plen(lookup(Y,d)),Plen(k)) ? concat(k,b) : lookup(Y,d)), lambda:plus(k,b))
)                         <anti-indent>
=bhG                      assign_copy('b',head(G))
I<G9999                   if less_than(G,9999):
 XZb.x?>l@Yblk+k\C@Yb+k\C     no_print(Z[b]=try_and_catch(greater_than(Plen(lookup(Y,b)),Plen(k)) ? concat(k,"C") : lookup(Y,b)), lambda:plus(k,"C"))
)                         <anti-indent>
)                     <anti-indent>
=YZ                   assign('Y',Z)
)                 <anti-indent>
@YQ               print(lookup(Y,Q))
```

Comment: Just noting: The lua one is below. :P  But this is amazing, good work.

Comment: Is still above for me :o

Comment: I sort by active, maybe you have votes. But it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Oh it's below for me now lol

Answer (score 5):

## Lua, 327763 steps (optimum, 276 bytes)

Golfed version:

```
a={[0]=""}t=tonumber for i=0,52 do A={}for k,v in pairs(a)do A[k]=v L=("%04d"):format(k)for i=1,4 do c=L:sub(i,i)d=L:gsub(c,(t(c)+1)%10)e=a[t(d)]A[d]=(not e or #e>#v)and v..c or e end b=k+1 if k<9999then e=a[b]A[b]=(not e or #e>#v)and v.."C"or e end end a=A endprint(a[(...)])
```

Improved version of the examples in question (only `1000` is improved):

```
0001:C
0093:CCCCCCCCCC12345678CCC
1000:0CCCCCCCCCCC2345678C23456789
     (0000>1111>1122>1199>1200>1000)
9999:012345678
```

Ungolfed version:

```
a = {[0]=""}
for i=0,52 do
    A = {}
    for k,v in pairs(a) do
        A[k] = v
        L=("%04d"):format(k)
        for i=1,4 do
           c=L:sub(i,i)
           d=L:gsub(c,(tonumber(c)+1)%10)
           e=a[tonumber(d)]
           A[d] = (not e or #e > #v) and v..c or e
        end
        b=k+1
        if k < 9999 then
            e=a[b]
            A[b] = (not e or #e > #v) and v.."C" or e
        end
    end
    a=A
end
print(a[93],a[1000],a[9999])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, score 512710

```
Unprotect[StringRepeat]
StringRepeat[x_String, 0]:=""
Protect[StringRepeat]
#<>StringRepeat["C",#3-#2*1111]&[Array[ToString@#&,#,0],##]&[If[#<10^3,0,Quotient[#,1111]],#]&
```

Fixes a bug with `StringRepeat` (behaves incorrectly for `StringRepeat[x_String,0]`)

Comment: Does there need to be a space in `StringRepeat[x_String, 0]:=""`?

Comment: Nope, but I was too lazy to remove it. Is that a problem?

Comment: Not at all :P It was just curious to me that the rest of the code is golfed except for *one* whitespace.

Comment: ... that *is* golfed, right? Or is Mathematica the new line noise?

Comment: @cat This isn't [tag:code-golf]

Comment: @pppery and yet the code looks golfed

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 327763 steps (optimum, 184 bytes)

A Breadth First Search, not so smart and not so fast.

```js
t=>eval("for(k=[],s=[['0000',i='']];[u,p]=s[i++],u-t;k[v=(1+u-~0+'').slice(-4)]=k[v]||s.push([v,p+'C']))[...u].map(x=>k[v=[...u].map(y=>x-y?y:-~x%10).join``]=k[v]||s.push([v,p+x]));p")
```

**Less golfed**

```js
t=>{
  k=[]; // mark values already found to reduce search
  for( i=0, s=[['0000','']]; 
       [u,p]=s[i++], // u: current code, p:current steps
       u != t; // exit if target found
     )
  {
     // try all digits present in current code
     [...u].map(x=> {
       v=[...u].map(y=>x-y?y:-~x%10).join`` // apply digit x to u
       if (!k[v]) // check if value v not found already
          k[v] = s.push([v,p+x]));
     })
     v=(1+u-~0+'').slice(-4); // try operator C
     if (!k[v]) // check if value v not found already
       k[v] = s.push([v,p+'C']))
  }
  return p
}
```

**Test**

```js
f=t=>eval("for(k=[],s=[['0000',i='']];[u,p]=s[i++],u-t;k[v=(1+u-~0+'').slice(-4)]=k[v]||s.push([v,p+'C']))[...u].map(x=>k[v=[...u].map(y=>x-y?y:-~x%10).join``]=k[v]||s.push([v,p+x]));p")

function SingleTest()
{
  var i=S.value
  if (/^\d{4}$/.test(i)) X.value=f(i)
  else X.value='invalid input'
}  

SingleTest()

function LongTest()
{
  var i=0,v,r,t=0
  
  var step=_=>{ 
    v = ('000'+i).slice(-4);
    r = f(v);
    t+= r.length    
    V.value = v;
    R.value = r;
    T.value = t;
    ++i;
    if(i<10000) setTimeout(step, 0)
  }  
  
  step()
}
```

```css
#V,#T,#S { width:5em }
#R,#X { width: 25em }
```

```html
Single Test <input id=S value='0093'><button onclick="SingleTest()">-></button><input readonly id=X><hr>
Long test (0000 ... 9999) <button onclick="LongTest()">Go</button>(i mean <i>long</i>, runtime 1 hour)<br>
<input readonly id=V>
<input readonly id=R> 
Total steps:<input readonly id=T>
```